# Android: Should I do more to manage memory or just rely on garbage collection?

Tags: android, caching, memory-management, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I'm still rather green in android development and I'm self-taught so this question may be rather basic. I have an app in the Play Store and I've been getting a number of out of memory errors via the console.

I save a lot of game data to Shared Preferences (best score, best time, current score, current time, positions, number of moves, move history, etc.). My game is a playing card game, so I need to record the positions of each of the 52 cards (x,y,z, visibility, face up/down, etc.) when on pause is called, I do this via Shared Preferences. I do this so I can reconstruct the game when On Resume is called.

During the game play, I've noticed my app can save a lot to the Cache and Data, for example:

- App: 58.15 MB
- **Data: 9.49 MB** *(I think this may be a problem)*
- Cache 770 kB

I have a strong suspicion the Data Size is far too large and could be absorbing too much memory on many devices. ***I've checked for memory leaks, and there are none.***

Based on some recent research I've done I've added some conditional tests, for example to check if the memory is low:

```
ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memoryInfo = getAvailableMemory();

        if(memoryInfo.lowMemory) {
            
           // don't save game metrics to Shared Preferences 
           sharePref.edit().clear.apply();
        }
```

I've come across other conditional test, for example to test if the ram is low:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        boolean result = am.isLowRamDevice();
```

I've also observed on stack overflow methods to delete the data, delete the cache and ComponentCallbacks2.

However, these are my main questions:

A) Is my Data usage too much? Is that size unusual?
B) In general, how can I reduce that size of data saved (Beyond reduced what is saved to Shared Preferences)? Or is that strictly handled by garbage collection?

For example, when the player opens the app for the first time they see a how to play UI (handled by a stub). This UI uses images. When the players closes the stub, there is no need to have any of those images that were displayed in the UI to be held in the cache or data, those images will never be accessed again.

Basically, If I can call test and identify that the memory is low, how can I identify specific elements in the Data or Cache to delete?

Comment: What does the OOM exception stacktrace lead to, what line, what is the cause? I doubt it is SharedPref, but it is still possible, because SharedPref is loaded into memory in the beginning and new reads/writes happen from memory (not file). My suspicion is your images on the ui, especially if you're using Bitmaps.